# Using url.resolve in angularjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Newbie question: I'd like to use Node's URL module (http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) in AngularJS.

e.g.

```
var url = require('url')
url.resolve('http://example.com/', '/one')
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Node is on the server.  Angular is on the client.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.

You could use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), or you could simply use a different library meant for URL manipulation in the browser.

[URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) comes to mind.